# pandas certain rows dataframe merging

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

```
print(ScimEn.head(20))
    Rank             Country
0      1               China
1      2       United States
2      3               Japan
3      4      United Kingdom
4      5  Russian Federation
5      6              Canada
6      7             Germany
7      8               India
8      9              France
9     10         South Korea
10    11               Italy
11    12               Spain
12    13                Iran
13    14           Australia
14    15              Brazil
15    16              Taiwan
16    17              Turkey
17    18              Norway
18    19         Netherlands
19    20              Sweden
```

I would like to merge this DF to another but only rows which are ranked [0:15].
If I do regular:

```
dfs = [ScimEn, energy, GDP[year].reset_index()]
newdf = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on='Country'), dfs)
newdf = newdf.set_index('Country')
print(len(newdf))
```

I have a DF of 140 entries, but I would like to have a DF of 15 entries per ranking mentioned above.
I had also tried:

```
 dfs = [ScimEn.where(ScimEn['Rank'] < 15), energy, GDP[year].reset_index()]
newdf = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on='Country'), dfs)
newdf = newdf.set_index('Country')
print(len(newdf))
```

But it returned 4 entries only.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the dfs you're trying to merge to?

Comment: You could slice the ScimEn dataframe to what you need first then merge normally. `ScimEn[ScimEn['Rank'] < 15]` will return your needed df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can filter by [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
dfs = [ScimEn.query("Rank < 15"), energy, GDP[year].reset_index()]
newdf = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on='Country'), dfs)
newdf = newdf.set_index('Country')
print(len(newdf))
```

Or by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) as mentioned [`Phong Phung comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43933492/pandas-certain-rows-dataframe-merging/43933840#comment74899694_43933492):

```
dfs = [ScimEn[ScimEn['Rank'] < 15], energy, GDP[year].reset_index()]
newdf = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on='Country'), dfs)
newdf = newdf.set_index('Country')
print(len(newdf))
```